# Why does this implementation of move corresponding work?

Tags: vb.net

Since three is read only and depends on a non property (four). Three should be undefined.
How does props, which does not set four, set three to the correct value?

```
public sub main
    Dim x1 = New one, x2 = New two
    x1.one = 3
    MoveCorresponding(x1, x2)
end sub

Public Sub MoveCorresponding(a As Object, b As Object, Optional ignoreList As List(Of String) = Nothing)
    Dim oType As Type = b.GetType
    Dim iType = a.GetType
    Dim props = iType.GetProperties()
    For Each pInf As PropertyInfo In props
        Dim parName = pInf.Name
        If pInf.CanWrite Then
            Try
                Dim val = pInf.GetValue(a, Nothing)
                pInf.SetValue(b, val)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End If
    Next

End Sub

End Class

Class one
    Public Property one As String = "1"
    Dim four As Integer = 1
    Public ReadOnly Property three As Integer
        Get
            Return four * 10
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

You set `four` on the same line that you declare it:

```
Dim four As Integer = 1 '<-- see?  it's set to "1".
```

The property `three` is simply computed from `four`:

```
Return four * 10
```

Am I not understanding your question?